# How to text warp "bulge/fisheye" like effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to find a way to create a similar effect like the image below with CSS or any other way. In Photoshop you transform the mesh of the selection. I tried using the `border-radius: 10% / 50%;` property on the div containing the text but that does not affect the text, only the div. I did use the `-webkit-` prefix as well. If there is any way to create this effect it would be great. Help is appreciated.

[image: the top and bottom corners are not as wide as the middle of the text.]

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` can't do such thing for you. Currently there's nothing in css standard can achieve effects like this.

The nearest thing is css `transform` property ([standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property)) which can do **linear transformation** on elements, but the effect in your image is **non-linear transformation**. So, you have to provide image instead of text.