# How To Create A Distorted/Warped Effect With CSS

Tags: javascript, css, sass, less

What I want to do is to recreate the old tv's look.
I want it to have a distorted effect where the text in the centre of the screen is a bit larger than the edges of the screen.

her's a picture of the shape that I'm going for:
[image]
[image]

Comment: try get helped with this:https://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. but thanks for the help :D

Comment: how does this effect call in photoshop/...

Comment: If the text was an image, this code example could help you — wrap image in 3D cylinder — http://cssdeck.com/labs/wrap-image-in-3d-cylinder-2

Comment: @לבנימלכה I think warp or distort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to text warp "bulge/fisheye" like effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824044/how-to-text-warp-bulge-fisheye-like-effect)

Comment: Try to check canvas and webGl